# In CSS, * selector winning over !important

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I made with Angular various components. One of this, a custom Modal, got me a strange behaviour.

This is the part of the LESS file for the Modal style.

```
app-modal{
  .modal{
    .modal-title{
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px 10px 0;
      height: 28px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    }    
    &.modal-info{
      .modal-title{
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 113) !important;
        color: rgb(208, 208, 208) !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the main style.less file, I have this

```
*{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
```

But the result from the chrome debugger is as per image

[image]

Why is the * selector taking precedence over the !important selector??